# Unable to refresh data for reports based on on-premise database (Gateway not working)

Tags: office365, powerbi, office365-apps

I have created some reports which are referencing to the on-premise SQL Server database via Power BI gateway. I have created a refresh schedule for all these reports.

The reports were refreshing correctly till recently, but somehow the reports are now not refreshing now. I tried to investigate for the issue, and as a first step I verified and confirmed Gateway was still up and running. But when I tried to check the refresh schedule of the reports, I found the controls in "Gateway Connection" tab are stuck and not responding. This is happening for all existing reports, as well as I tried creating a new report and still it was showing the same. It doesn't proceed even after waiting for half an hour.

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Could you please assist as early as possible?

his issue makes the product of no use for us honestly. We are unable to refresh (manual as well as scheduled) any report at all.!!!

I have already posted this on community.microsoft.com, but waiting for a response since almost one week.

Thanks

Nirman

Comment: You can try re-installing gateway, as there may be some changes in power BI azure which need latest power Bi gateway to be installed.

Comment: yes, that was the case. Sorry for the late response on this. Please post this as an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try re-installing gateway, as there may be some changes in Power BI azure which need latest Power BI gateway to be installed. Make sure you uninstall it completely as upgrade may not work, In my case I had to re-install it  after uninstalling it.